# SQLite Datetime Conversion?

Tags: android, sqlite

I m developing android application. I need to convert `datetime` into date. 
I want to convert `'25-07-2013 11:44AM'` (datetime) into `'25-07-2013'` (date). 
I am trying this function to convert `SELECT date('25-07-2013 11:44AM')`, but it was not working.
Please suggest some solution for this problem.

Comment: Is this a SQLite question? You can manipulate date on Java. SQLite doesn't have any date data type.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this page](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), it does not seem that am/pm times are supported in `date` SQLite function (this should be noted as `h` or `K` according to the [date format specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) of Java at least; also it is explicitly mentioned `%H hour: 00-24`). Maybe experiment if using 24 hour clock will not trigger the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are search for Java code or SQL code , but if it is Java code then solution could be this :

```
String date  = "25-07-2014 11:44AM";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String newDate = dateFormat.format(dateFormat.parse(date));
        System.out.println(newDate);
```

If in case your are looking for SQL code let me know I will share that as well.

Comment: I m using websql in javascript.